# object is a class in python, but its first char is not capitalized

Tags: python

I am learning Python these days (from Code Accademy). As I was working with the classes, they mentioned as a naming convention class name's first letter is capitalized.

but when I see the class declaration, they always use superclass "object". i.e. first character is not capital. Although its just a naming converntion, does it has any special meaning too?

is there anything am missing?

Comment: Note that most built-in class names are lower case. Go figure. Coding conventions are arbitrary and often contradictory.

Comment: Can you give an example of such? I'm a bit confused by your description.

Comment: @drum Coding conventions (see [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)) suggest leading upper-case, camel case for class names. But python classes such as `object` don't follow that convention.

Comment: @juanchopanza thanks for the Link. clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PEP8 suggests to use `CapWords` (or `PascalCase`) [convention for class names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names), but it is mentioned that builtins follow a different convention:

> Note that there is a separate convention for builtin names: most
>   builtin names are single words (or two words run together), with the
>   CapWords convention used only for exception names and builtin
>   constants.

I should mention that PEP8 uses different names for naming styles than most of us ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72(v=vs.71).aspx), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase)):

```
common naming     pep8 naming
-------------     -----------
PascalCase        CapitalizedWords, CapWords, CamelCase
camelCase         mixedCase
```